# Out of Memory in command line execution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console-application

Hi my program was built in 64 bit and I have configured 
[image]

```
  <runtime>  
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />  
  </runtime>
```

And I have sufficient memory.

It runs OK in Visual Studio in both debug and release mode.

When I use command line execution it will give me "Out of Memory" Error

Could anyone have any idea on this?

Comment: If by "command line", you mean "console application", can you check what the setting is for the "prefer 32 bit" compiler flag in the options of that executable project? My guess it is checked which means your application is being started as a 32-bit process. If all the code and all the referenced assemblies are AnyCpu, then you can simply uncheck that setting and rebuild.

Comment: Please, share your project settings and code sample

Comment: Anything useful in the Windows event log?

Answer (score -1):

I found it,

The problem is missing configuration file.

Copy the `exe` file into another directory without copy the `exe.config` file.
Then there is no `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />` in the run time.